# Why does my program work despite wrong placement of my function and cout statements?

Tags: c++, function

Ideally, some of the content of my Fahrenheit function should be placed in the main function but wanted to try something out. I asked for the user input in the Fahrenheit function and after this, I called the Fahrenheit function after the `cout` statement. I expected the "Your temperature..." string to display first nevertheless it asked for the input before proceeding to print the string. Why is this so?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int FahrenheitConv();
int main ()
{
    cout << "Your temperature in Fahrenheit is "<< FahrenheitConv();
    return 0;
}

int FahrenheitConv()
{
    double centigrade;
    cout << "What is your temperature in centigrade: ";
    cin >> centigrade;

    double fahrenheit = (1.8) * (centigrade ) + 32;
    return fahrenheit;
}
```

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list. Welcome to SO.

Comment: The evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified. I am sure, that there is a duplicate somewhere..

Comment: The order is unspecified, see in this [example](https://repl.it/repls/AngelicTremendousScientificcomputing), I get the string you expect printed first.

Comment: `std::cout << x << y;` is syntactic sugar for `operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, x), y)` and as mentioned before evaluation order of the arguments of a function is unspecified. So `y` may be evaluated before `std::cout << x`.

Comment: Yet another good reason to keep user interaction and data processing separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> **1.9 Program Execution [intro.execution]**
>
> [...] Except where noted, **evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual
> expressions are unsequenced.** [ *Note*: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the execution
> of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions **need not be
> performed consistently in different evaluations.** — *end note* ] [...]

So you can't really expect any particular order, unless for really specific cases such as logical operators and the ternary operator, which introduce sequence points.

Comment: Thanks, Arnav. I did the same thing in Dev C++ and it asked for input first. Thanks again for clarifying

Comment: IIRC, C++17 forces on order for some things such as the `<<` operator. Do you know if I'm remembering right?